# Get value of string.xml in android

Tags: android, sqlite

my question is simple. How can i get access to the string value in res/values/string.xlm in a extends SQLiteOpenHelper because getString method is use with an Activity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can get context object through constructor.

```
class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private Context mContext;
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        mContext = context;
    }
}
```

Comment: and use this `mContext` to get `String` from `strings.xml`

Answer (score 1):

**Try**

Receive  `Context` in your `SQLiteOpenHelper` class and then use Context like

```
   context.getResources().getString(R.string.yourStringNameFromStrings);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a reference to `Context`. The constructor of `SQLiteOpenHelper` accepts a context, you can save it in a local variable. If `c` is context variable, and `myString` is the name of string resource in `strings.xml`, then you can get string value as:

```
C.getString(R.string.myString);
```